# How to create pipeline with jenkins?

Tags: jenkins, continuous-integration, cicd

I followed this [tutorial](https://youtu.be/m0a2CzgLNsc) and when i get to 29:32 the option "Build Pipeline View" is not displayed in the list i only get list view and my view.What can be the cause of this ? ( i followed every step carefully)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a plugin that you can install.

Plugin Name: Build Pipeline

Plugin Web page: https://plugins.jenkins.io/build-pipeline-plugin/

Comment: thank you so much i thought every required plugin was installed at first !!